# Drop Update on Column if value is NULL or Blank

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

### Edit for Background

I am working on an app that is regularly having columns overwritten with blank data. It is proprietary front end on a relatively simple SQL database.  I do not have access to the front end code, the data in this table is mainly static in the sense that once it is entered it should not change and should never be blank.  I would like to try to remedy this issue from the back end (the only option I have) by dropping updates that result in certain columns being set to `''` or `null`

What would be the most elegant way to prevent an update that was `blank` or `null` if the column was already populated with data.  For instance if you had a nvarchar column `Name` that had the value of `John Smith` and the update procedure passed in `''` or `NULL` keep the Value `John Smith` if it had another name `Jane Doe` proceed with the update.  The first thing that comes to mind is to do this with a trigger, however I know these can be messy and affect other code that is being executed.  Any thoughts ?

Comment: Can you shed more light? what's causing the update? why even have an update if it's "wrong"?

Comment: @Amit see edit for background

Comment: A `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger is probably what you need.

Comment: I'd take that front end app offline. That will keep it from trashing the data.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24734/restrict-update-on-certain-columns-only-allow-stored-procedure-to-update-those

Comment: @Amit Unfortunately this is their production application so that is not an option.

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna - I didn't really believe that was a viable option :-/

Comment: The code that applies the update - i.e. where it says `UPDATE MyTable SET name = whatever_unsanitised_rubbish_is_entered` - can you edit that, or is it part of the front end?

Comment: @MikeK There is a stored procedure for the update that is very generic, are you suggesting that I put a case statement in there ?  My concern is that they have inline t-sql in the application somewhere that does not use the stored proc.

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna: my thinking was to frame each update with `ISNULL(NULLIF(update_value,''),update_value), original_value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger you can do like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER YourTable_ConditionalUpdate
   ON YourTable
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN   
UPDATE YourTable SET  /* update all fields from original update except Name field */
    Field1 = i.Field1,
    Field2 = i.Field2,
    Field3 = i.Field3
FROM YourTable 
INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.PrimaryKey = YourTable.PrimaryKey

UPDATE YourTable SET  /* update Name only if it's not empty */
    Name = i.Name
FROM YourTable
INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.PrimaryKey = YourTable.PrimaryKey
WHERE NULLIF(i.Name, '') Is NOT NULL
END
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the update.  If I had it with multiple columns I would just duplicate the second update statement and remove the field from the group update correct ?  Also can you think of any caveats or unintended consequences from using this.

Comment: Yes thats right. And I can't think of any problems right now by using this approach.